# React.js TypeScript Same component for <input /> and <textarea />

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, react-props

I have created an `<Input />` component with some base - helper components for better usability and minimizing the code inside the main component. However, I would like to create also a `<textarea />` HTML element. I am using **React.js** with **TypeScript**. So, the props and most specifically the input event props overwrite each other, and the compiler complains. Is there anything that I can do, except for writing the same code inside the `<Multiline />` component?

***Note**: I am wrapping the component with `React.forwardRef` for forwarding and passing a `ref` to the input component*

#### UPDATE: Add code snippet

**Input/Input.tsx**

```
export default class Input extends React.Component<FProps, State> {    
  static displayName = "Input";

  state: State = {
    id: this.props.id || "",
    value: this.props.value || this.props.defaultValue || "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.id) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, id: generateInputId() }));
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newVal = e.target.value;
    const { onChange } = this.props;

    this.setState({ value: newVal });

    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { id, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <InputContextProvider value={{ ...this.props, value, id, onChange: this.handleChange }}>
        <InputContainer>
          <FieldContainer />
        </InputContainer>
      </InputContextProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Input/**helpers**/FieldContainer.tsx**

```
export const FieldContainer: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const {
    value: propsValue,
    type,
    label,
    id,
    defaultValue,
    className,
    state = "default",
    placeholder,
    floatingplaceholder,
    prefix,
    suffix,
    characterLimit,
    maxLength,
    allowClear,
    onChange,
    forwardref,
    ...rest
  } = useInputContext();

  const isDisabled = useDisabled(rest, state);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | number>(propsValue || defaultValue || "");
  const [prefixWidth, setPrefixWidth] = useState<number>(0);
  const [suffixWidth, setSuffixWidth] = useState<number>(0);

  const prefixRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const suffixRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  // TODO: Replace with <Icon /> component
  if (allowClear) {
    // suffix = <>
  }

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newVal = e.target.value;

    if (characterLimit && maxLength && String(newVal).length > maxLength) {
      return;
    }

    setValue(newVal);

    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prefixRef && prefixRef.current) {
      const prefixWidth = prefixRef.current.offsetWidth;
      setPrefixWidth(prefixWidth);
    }
    if (suffixRef && suffixRef.current) {
      const suffixWidth = suffixRef.current.offsetWidth;
      setSuffixWidth(suffixWidth);
    }
  }, [prefix, suffix]);

  return (
    <OuterFieldContainer prefixWidth={prefixWidth}>
      <FixGroup group={prefix} ref={prefixRef} position="left" />
      <Base
        id={id}
        value={value}
        className={className}
        state={state}
        placeholder={floatingplaceholder === false && placeholder ? placeholder : undefined}
        disabled={isDisabled}
        onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
        ref={forwardref}
        style={{
          paddingLeft: prefix ? `${(prefixWidth + DEFAULT_PADDING) / EM_REM_MULTIPLIER}em` : "",
          paddingRight: suffix ? `${(suffixWidth + DEFAULT_PADDING) / EM_REM_MULTIPLIER}em` : "",
        }}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        {...rest}
      />
      <FixGroup group={suffix} ref={suffixRef} position="right" />
    </OuterFieldContainer>
  );
};
```

**Input/**helpers**/Base/Base.tsx**

```
export const Base = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((componentProps, ref) => {
  const {
    id: propsId,
    value,
    placeholder,
    type,
    floatingplaceholder,
    state = "default",
    onChange,
    style,
    children: propsChildren,
    characterLimit,
    overrideOnChange,
    allowClear,
    ...props
  } = useInputContext();

  const id = useInputId(propsId);
  const [classNames, rest] = useClassnames("input", props, { stateToRemove: { state } });
  const isDisabled = useDisabled(props, state);

  // return type === "textarea" ? (
  //   <textarea
  //     id={id}
  //     className={classNames}
  //     value={value || ""}
  //     placeholder={placeholder}
  //     disabled={isDisabled}
  //     aria-disabled={isDisabled}
  //     aria-label={placeholder}
  //     ref={ref}
  //     // * Enable / disabled the Grammarly extension
  //     // data-gramm="false"
  //     cols={28}
  //     rows={5}
  //     {...rest}
  //   />
  // ) : (
  return (
    <input
      id={id}
      type={type}
      className={classNames}
      value={value}
      placeholder={!floatingplaceholder ? placeholder : undefined}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      aria-disabled={isDisabled}
      aria-label={placeholder}
      ref={ref}
      data-hasfloatingplaceholder={floatingplaceholder}
      data-testid="input"
      onChange={e => onChange && onChange(e)}
      style={style}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
});
```

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63963850/react-typescript-forwardref-types-for-an-element-which-returns-either-an-input-o/64018005#64018005

Comment: It is a really helpful answer. But I would like to pass the `e` (event) type at the `onChange()` function, as the parent component can have access to all the attributes. Check my comment on @gazdagero's answer

Answer (score 3):

What about using the same component with a boolean like `multiLine` and spreading some `...props` to handle the different props of input and textarea (if there is any difference).

```
const Input:FC<{
  multiLine: Boolean
  [key:string]: any
}> = ({ multiLine, ...props }) => {
  if (multiLine) return <textarea {...props} />
  return <input {...props} />
}
```

Comment: I am using various components before and after the base `<input />` element, that are included in the `<Input />` component. What I mean, is that I change the input value while the user types in the `<Input />` component, and then if another component wants it to be available at it parent layer, they can access the `onChange` prop from there. So, the props are fine, but the `onChange()` function complains, when `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>`

Comment: Can you add a minimal code snippet pls, which includes the data handling in parent and this onChange stuff.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just hope the structure is not so complicated.

Comment: Yes, a little bit complicated. Can you remove the unrelated part (outer wrapper etc) to show better the problematic part?

Comment: Also would be great to know what is the expected behaviour, what functionality would you like achieve with this structure. It is also not clear for me what the <Base /> component is? Looks like a HOC base from its name, but it is not.

Comment: With this structure I use the Context API, and I eliminate the code in the main `<Input />` component, and split it to other smaller helper components; some of them are reusable

Comment: Here, I will update my question with the `<Base />` component's code

Comment: Well, having a look on the `Base` component I do not see any reason why to combine the input and textarea within one component. Some redundancy in the implementation of two similar components is not enough reason to glue them together into a complicated one.
Also when you use it it does not bring any advantage to fill a "type" prop instead of typing `<Input` or `<Textbox` as node name.

Comment: Yes, you are possibly right. I have not done anything else rather than that till now. I mean I still keep my `<textarea />` and `<input />` elements to different components

Comment: Any idea on how I can use same reusabIe attributes on `<input />` and `<textarea />`?

Comment: If you'd like to extend both component with the same attributes adding a special feature to both of them you can implement a [HOC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56392603/5506730) like `withNoGrammar` etc. But I do not think that redundancy is something which you have to avoid at all costs.